# Calculate height of XRTableCell rendering

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm working on a report where I need to calculate the actual height of a XRTableCell. I tried to override the `BeforePrint` XRTableCell but it reports the height used in the designer.

How would you obtain the actual size of the rendered cell?

Answer (score 0):

The BeforePrint and AfterPrint events are issued before the actual rendering is done.
You can hook into the Draw event to record the dimensions used, but this information may come to too late for you to be able to usefully use it.

The Draw event is repeated if the preview surface is altered, e.g. if the margins are adjusted.

```
public partial class XtraReport1 : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport {
    public XtraReport1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void xrTableCell1_BeforePrint( object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e ) {
        // Called 1st.
    }

    void xrTableCell1_AfterPrint( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        // Called 2nd.
    }    

    float xrTableCell1_RenderHeight = 0;
    void xrTableCell1_Draw( object sender, DrawEventArgs e ) {

        // Called 3rd. And repeated if the preview window is altered. (e.g. Margins moved)
        XRTableCell cell = sender as XRTableCell;
        xrTableCell1_RenderHeight = e.Bounds.Height;
    }    
}
```